# Saved data has undesired quotation marks

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using the following code to export my data frame to csv:

```
data.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(delimiter="\t", codec="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec").save('s3a://myBucket/myPath')
```

Note that I use `delimiter="\t"`, as I don't want to add additional quotation marks around each field. However, when I checked the output csv file, there are still some fields which are enclosed by quotation marks. e.g.

```
abcdABCDAAbbcd ....
1234_3456ABCD  ...
"-12345678AbCd"  ...
```

It seems that the quotation mark appears when the leading character of a field is "-". Why is this happening and is there a way to avoid this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't use all the options provided by the CSV writer. It has `quoteMode` parameter which takes one of the four values (descriptions from the `org.apache.commons.csv` [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/QuoteMode.html_):

- `ALL` - *quotes all fields*
- `MINIMAL` (default) - *quotes fields which contain special characters such as a delimiter, quotes character or any of the characters in line separator*
- `NON_NUMERIC` - *quotes all non-numeric fields*
- `NONE` - *never quotes fields*

If want to avoid quoting the last options looks a good choice, doesn't it?