# Data is getting wrapped in the double quotes for Hive's CHAR data types if there is trailing space in it

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am writing data of a hive table in csv file in HDFS.

My hive table has a `CHAR(5)` column.

Sample data in CHAR datatype:

```
aaaaa
bb
```

Data in CSV file in HDFS after spark job:

```
aaaaa
"bb   "
```

If there are space characters in the CHAR data type, it's getting wrapped in the double quotes. If there is no leading/trailing space it's working fine (no double quotes).

Useful code:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true).setMaster("yarn-cluster").setAppName("SAMPLE_APP");
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
HiveContext hc = new HiveContext(sc);
DataFrame df = hc.table("testdb.tbl1");
df.printSchema();
DataFrameWriter writer = df.repartition(1).write();
writer.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(outputHdfsFile);
```

I am not sure it's a feature or bug. But can I disable it?

Comment: A feature: [Saved data has undesired quotation marks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37725033)

Comment: @zero323 good feature..:P